# Изменить символ в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Похоже я просто затроил, но не пойму как сделать банальщину.

```
Условие ? тогда минус : тогда плюс;

var Value = $('Элемент').val();
$('Элемент').val(+Value Минус/Плюс 100 );
```

Вот не пойму как в значение элемента передать минус или плюс из первого условия.
Ведь если присвоить какой нить переменной '-' или '+' и передать в

> $('Элемент').val(+Value Минус/Плюс 100 );

то это будет просто строка.
Можно арифметическую манипуляцию добавить в первое условие, но как то не правильно это. Получится почти один и тот же код в двух местах.

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var factor = Условие ? -1 : 1;
$('Элемент').val(+Value + factor * 100);
```

Comment: Плюс, но откровенно говоря, это усложняет читаемость.

Comment: оу, классно) всё гениальное просто))